# Kiss sb good night/goodbye(meaning)—?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**He kissed the children good night/goodbye.**

Kiss sb good night —I don't think it have any literal meaning,It is an idiomatic phrase I think??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (usually) literal - kissing somebody as part of a goodbye or good night ritual.

It can also be used metaphorically: "Kiss your X goodbye" means "you are going to lose X".

Comment: But, **as a part of goodbye** is an implied meaning i thought.

Comment: The *kiss [valued thing] **goodbye*** version is *usually* metaphorical (no osculation involved; besides - who can kiss their own ass? :). But the *kiss [valued person] **goodnight*** version is almost always literal (but just a peck on the cheek, not sexualized "snogging").

Comment: "He gave the children a kiss while wishing them goodnight."